# Reload Angular page data after routing

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a chat box page on the photo below designed with [Nebular](https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/card/overview#nbcardcomponent):
[Chat box photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HGEj.png)

When I click to one of the list name (2) the URL ID (1) changed but the data by that ID doesn't load.

**N.B**
I have create a module named `chatting` containing the name list of users, then a component named `message` containing the chat box.

`chatting.component.html`

```
<li *ngFor="let x of userdata  | filter: Search" >
            <a [routerLink]="['/message/', x.id]" href="">
```

`chatting-routing.module.ts`

```
children:[
  {
    path:'message/:id',
    component:MessageComponent
  },
```

`message.component.ts`

```
getdata()
{
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

  this.cr.getuserbyid(this.id).subscribe(res=>{
    this.tabs=res;
    this.username=this.tabs.firstName;
  })


}
```

**NB**: I tried with the `location.reload()` and `window.location.reload()` but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could subscribe to route or activated route in for example ngOnit in your component. Maybe something like this :

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params)=>{
        return this.cr.getuserbyid(params.get('id'));
    })).subscribe(res=>{
      this.tabs=res;
      this.username=this.tabs.firstName;
    })
}
```

In the example above you are subscribing the activatedRoute service which will detect route changes. When this observable is emitting you are passing the output from that into your getuserId observable. The switchMap will cancel the inner observable (getuserbyid) if the outer observable (route/activatedRoute) is emitting a new value.

Instead of having these component variables tabs and username you could to subscribe directly in the template with the async pipe.